# JFace: How to get caller of Action#run()?

Tags: java, jface

I have a ContentProvider for a Tree view. There I add some actions that can be performed on an item of the tree. The method looks like this:

```
private void makeActions() {
   action1 = new Action() {

   @Override
   public void runWithEvent(Event event) {
      System.out.println(event);
      System.out.println(event.data.getClass());
      //How can I find the caller of runWithEvent?          
   }    
};
```

How can I find the object of the tree that has caused the call of Action#runWithEvent?

Comment: What about event#widget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using the new Command API instead of the older Action API. In the new API, you can easily access the relevant information in the handler for the command.